# bash: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

This fails:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

N_TIMES="$1"
for ((n = 0; n < $N_TIMES; n++)); do
  # command
done
```

Setting the variable manually also fails:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

N_TIMES=10
for ((n = 0; n < $N_TIMES; n++)); do
  # command
done
```

Both return:

```
 Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Why isn't the loop able to read the variable as a number for iteration? How should it be to be able to read the first argument as the number of times to run the command?

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: ...to make things even more complex, `sh` (POSIX sh, a specification from the early 90s that's most directly influenced by late-80s iterations of David Korn's ksh) isn't Bourne (Stephen Bourne's shell from the 1970s) on any modern OS. "Bourne again" is a cute pun, but somewhat misleading.

Comment: (have I mentioned how glad I am that it's no longer the early 2000s when SunOS prevented me from making that "any modern OS" claim? Good riddance, &c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: warning] **If you use `sh script`, you pass the script in `POSIX` mode, even with `bash` shebang `#!/bin/bash`**.

The shebang is only used when you don't start an interpreter yourself: when you start an interpreter yourself, the OS doesn't have to do it for you, so nothing looks at the shebang.
It's pretty like the same as compiling [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) with a [c](/questions/tagged/c) compiler.

**So, don't use**:

```
sh script.sh
```

to execute script.

[image: note]
Instead, do:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

On my Debian like OS:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 oct.  28 04:48 /bin/sh -> dash*
```

---

Moreover, [don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

---

**Finally**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n_times=10
for ((n=0; n < n_times; n++)); do
  # command
done
```

No need sigil `$` in arithmetic.

Comment: Specifically, the observed error is what `dash` reports; OP's `/bin/sh` is likely a link to `dash`.

Comment: you mean, that when I run sh something, even with the shebang it will use the default shell?

Comment: If you use `sh script`, you pass the script in `POSIX` mode, even with `bash` shebang

Comment: Thanks. what do you mean by "you pass the script in POSIX mode"?

Comment: @YFl, `sh` is only guaranteed, on a POSIX-compliant operating system, to be a POSIX-compliant shell. It might be dash. It might be bash in sh mode. It might be ksh. It might be posh. It can be _anything_ as long as it's POSIXy.

Comment: @YFl, so you can only safely use `sh` if your code is written to be compatible with every existing POSIX-flavored shell -- which is to say, it needs to be code written to the POSIX sh standard. If you use `#!/bin/bash`, that's saying that your script **isn't** written for `sh`, so you can't safely use `sh` to run it. It's like trying to use a C compiler to compile C++ code.

Comment: ok. got you. So when I run `sh ...` I get the default POSIX-compliant shell in the given system, whatever it is. It will overwrite the shebang. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @YFl, exactly right. The shebang is only used when you don't start an interpreter yourself; when you start an interpreter yourself, the OS doesn't have to do it for you, so nothing looks at the shebang.

Comment: Perfect. That's correcting years of mistakes. Better late than never. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Charles, added this useful comment to my answer