# BASH script to create and sign a ES256 JWT token

Tags: bash, jwt, openssl, token, es256

I'm trying to make a BASH script that generates and signes a JWT token for AppStore Connect API. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests)

I currently have a BASH script and a Ruby script that both produce tokens from the same data. The token from Ruby works as supposed to, but the token created by the BASH script does not.

The produced header and payload are identical, so the problem is the signing using openssl in BASH.

BASH script that creates an invalid key:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if required tools are installed
if ! command -v openssl > /dev/null; then
  echo "Error: openssl not found. Please install openssl."
  exit 1
fi

# Replace with your actual values
key_id="MCHQZ23JLZ"
p8_file="AuthKey_${key_id}.p8"
issuer_id="69a6de92-655f-47e3-e053-5b8c7c11a4d1"
expiration_time=$(( $(date '+%s') + 1200 ))  # Token expires in 20 mins

# Create the header and payload
header='{"kid":"'$key_id'","typ":"JWT","alg":"ES256"}'
payload='{"iss":"'$issuer_id'","exp":'$expiration_time',"aud":"appstoreconnect-v1"}'

# Encode the header and payload to base64
encoded_header=$(echo -n "$header" | base64 | tr -d '\n=' | tr '/+' '_-')
encoded_payload=$(echo -n "$payload" | base64 | tr -d '\n=' | tr '/+' '_-')

# Create the signature
signature=$(echo -n "$encoded_header.$encoded_payload" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign "$p8_file" | openssl base64 -e -A | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '\n=')

# Combine the encoded header, payload, and signature to create the JWT token
jwt_token="$encoded_header.$encoded_payload.$signature"

echo "JWT Token: $jwt_token"
```

Ruby script that creates a valid working token:

```
require 'jwt'
require 'openssl'

# Variables
key_id = "MXXXXXXXXZ"
issuer_id = "6XxXXxx2-655f-47e3-e053-5xXXxxXXxxX1"
valid_duration = 20 * 60 # 20 minutes

private_key_path = "AuthKey_#{key_id}.p8"
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new IO.read private_key_path

headers = {
  'kid' => key_id,
  'typ' => "JWT"
}

claims = {
  'iss' => issuer_id,
  'exp' => Time.now.to_i + valid_duration,
  'aud' => 'appstoreconnect-v1'
}

token = JWT.encode claims, private_key, 'ES256', headers

puts token
```

The two scripts now creates identical headers and payload, but the signing must be wrong in the BASH script.

Any help in making the signing correct in the BASH script is appreciated.

Comment: To sign a token you need only the private key. To verify the token you need only the public key. So on jwt.io you would need to paste the public key to verify your token. If you provide the private key there and then change anything in the right column (i.e the decoded header or payload), jwt.io would calculate a new signature.

Comment: Thanks @jps, I don't know how to get that from Apples systems. I think the difference is in using -sign or -hmac, but I don't know the difference.
The token produced using -hmac doesent work, so something is not right.

Comment: hmac (HS256) is a totally different signature algorithm but afaik apple uses ES256. Sorry, beyond that I can't help here. But you can [derive the public key from a private key](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+public+key+from+private+key+ecdsa)

Comment: Since it's the -hmac command that produces the faulty signing, I won't spend more time on that if that's using a wrong signature.

Comment: If the -sign command uses the correct signature I'll have to solve the syntax error. Thanks. I'll edit the question and remove the -hmac example.

Comment: That error message suggests you're running the script with sh rather than bash (on macOS, /bin/sh *is* bash, but it runs with certain features disabled for compatibility reasons). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122906/bash-syntax-error-bad-for-loop-variable/76122947#76122947).

Comment: It could be that you are running an old bash version which can't do command substitution. Do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` at the top of your script to see what version is actually running it.

Comment: I'm running 3.2.57 and the latest version is 5.2. Will updating solve it?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks a lot. Running this with ./filename.sh does give another result, which I believe fixes the substitution. I now get the error: Could not find private key from /dev/fd/63. I assume this is a problem with the piping somewhere? I will update the question.

Comment: All those all-upper-case variable names might be clobbering some environment variables and so causing you problems, fix that first, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization). You also have a UUOC with `cat "$P8_FILE" | tr -d '\n'` instead of `tr -d '\n' < "$P8_FILE"`. YMMV with removing the `\n`s from any file as it's no longer a valid POSIX text file once you do that.

Comment: Regarding the error message `Could not find private key from /dev/fd/63` - didn't whatever produced that also tell you the name of the command producing it and possibly a line number? If so, please add that information to your question.

Comment: I suspect the private key is in the wrong format. I can't find it in the docs, but I think `openssl` expects it to be in PEM format. What's the .p8 file in? It looks like you're treating it as being base64-encoded DER, which doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I found out that it was a problem with how I load the private key file .p8. Loading it into a temporary file solves that. See updated code.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I think you are getting to the problem. The .p8-file contains the private key in PEM format. Encapsulated in -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----.

Are there anything wrong with my encoding then? My assumption was that PEM = base64 encoded version of DER. (https://serverfault.com/a/9717)

Comment: PEM is mostly base64-encoded DER, but you'd need to remove the `-----BEGIN...` and `-----END ...` lines before de-base64ing it. As for the current version, I take it the `openssl dgst ...` command is no longer failing? Also, why create a temp copy of the key file rather than using it directly? That seems unnecessary (and probably insecure, since it's likely to be in a public temp folder).

Comment: @GordonDavisson That's a good catch. Removing the ----BEGIN and ----END from the private token makes it possible to use the previous version where I use the token directly and not load it into a temp file. Thanks. Your help is awesome.

For some reason the token still haven't valid signing according to jwt.io and it doesen't work calling Apples API.

Is there a way I can check if the token has been signed correctly?
The header and body are correct when checking in jwt.io.

Comment: @EdMorton I updated the casing and the question with a working ruby script to compare.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I updated the question with a working ruby script to compare.
The token output is different created with riby and bash. So there must be a bug in the bash script.

Comment: Thanks for updating the capitalization, now copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issue(s) it'll tell you about then let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: @EdMorton Done. No issues detected! The signing from the BASH created token is still not valid.

Comment: One issue detected: `$ shellcheck myscriptLine 26:`
`echo -n $signature | openssl dgst -prverify "$p8_file" -signature
        ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.`

`Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
echo -n "$signature" | openssl dgst -prverify "$p8_file" -signature`

Comment: That COULD be your entire problem for all we know so there's no point further debugging a script while that issue exists in it, you've GOT to fix any issues shellcheck detects before asking actual people to potentially waste their time looking further. As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs: "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and `convert_ec` function solved the problem.
https://github.com/smallstep/cli/blob/master/integration/openssl-jwt.sh#L20C1-L27C2

```
function convert_ec {
    INPUT=$(openssl asn1parse -inform der)
    R=$(echo "$INPUT" | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f4)
    S=$(echo "$INPUT" | head -3 | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f4)

    echo -n $R | xxd -r -p
    echo -n $S | xxd -r -p
}
signature=$(echo -n "$encoded_header.$encoded_payload" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign "$p8_file" | convert_ec | openssl base64 -e -A | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '\n=')
```