# Why am I getting a bash error when I use vared or read command?

Tags: bash, unix

I am attempting to make a small bash script to remind me to drink water at a random time (roughly 30-45mins let's say). When the timer reaches to the magic random number, it will trigger the voice and remind me to drink water. In order to exit, useThis is something fun and silly to get back into coding a little bit and rewire myself a bit. I had this project for a while. Anyways, while looking at it and trying to make it functional, I attempted to write a `read input` in the code, but it displays me an error for `line 37: vared: command not found` or `line 37: read: command not found`

I'm slightly confused as to why exactly the issue is in here. I ran it separately with `varead` and `read`, and they are fine outside of the shell file.

This question sole purpose is not knowing the difference between zsh and bash altogether. Instead, it is to know *why* the script that I'm executing is not running it properly (even with the small tweaks suggested in the comments)

#### Idea

This script only runs when I open the terminal. So, I have a dotfile that executes this shell on my profile like this:

```
#Drink water reminder script
chmod +x Water-Reminder/drinkwater.sh
./drinkwater.sh
```

and inside of `drinkwater.sh` is the code.

#### Code

```
#!/bin/zsh

start_reminder()
{
    while :
    do
        input=''
        sleep_duration=$(((RANDOM % 10) + 15)) # Random number for the seconds for testing it out.
        sleep $sleep_duration
        printf "DRINK WATER YOU DINGUS\n"
        say DRINK WATER YOU DINGUS
        vared -p "Are you going to drink water? [y/n]: " -c input
        if [[ $input == 'Y' || $input == 'y' || $input == "yes" || $input == "YES" || $input == "Yes" ]]; then
            printf "okay :^) I will trust you\n"
        else
            echo "uwotm8?"
        fi
    done
}

start_reminder &
```

If it helps, I'm mainly using zsh. I tried to test it on bash too, but not doing the trick to my problem.

Comment: Why are you running `sh` if you actually want `bash` or `zsh`?  Why not use a `#!` line and make the script executable?

Comment: sh is bash on macOS. Run your script with zsh

Comment: `vared` is a zsh-only command; it's not available in either bash or generic sh-style shells. Use an explicit zsh shebang in the script (either `#!/bin/zsh` or `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`), and don't override that by specifying  an interpreter when you run it (i.e. run it with just `Water-Reminder/drinkwater.sh`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122906/bash-syntax-error-bad-for-loop-variable/76122947#76122947) (though it's about bash, not zsh).

Comment: You are tagging the question _bash_ **AND** _zsh_, but then run it as _sh_. Please make up your mind first which shell you are going to use, before complaining what does not work.

Comment: Sorry if my question sounds confusing, but regardless to what I'm trying to do (either in bash or zsh), I'm still encountering the same issue. What do you recommend me to do @user1934428 ?

Comment: Understand the difference between these shells. If your script was written for `zsh`, run it with `zsh drinkwater.sh` (or better yet set its [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to point to Zsh, `chmod +x` it, and simply run it by writing the path to the script). Understand that `zsh` is required to run scripts which contain Zsh syntax, Bash for Bash syntax, and `sh` for portable scripts which only contain POSIX shell syntax.

Comment: There is no shortcut which allows you to ignore the differences between these  three incompatible shells, other than not using the other two at all and concentrating exclusively on learning only one of them. Even then, if the one you choose is not `sh`, you will need to understand the differences between `sh` and your preferred shell eventually.

Comment: I already have the shebang initially, but I still yet don't understand why is not properly `varead` or `read` input in the first place when I want it to lol. It executes fine, but it does not even attempt to read the input

Comment: I feel it has to do something when I run the script in the background `&` is causing this strange behavior.

Comment: @ZeidTisnes Background processes are paused if they try to read from the terminal; see ["Why do backgrounded processes sometimes stop spontaneously?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/why-do-backgrounded-processes-sometimes-stop-spontaneously)

Comment: Your shebang is or is not resepcted, depending on how you execute the script. To give a precise description of you situation, not only post your script, but exaplain **how** you invoke it, and from what kind of interactive shell you invoke it.

Comment: What do you mean. I have a shebang in the beginning for zsh specifically. I `chmod +x` the file and execute it afterwards. It has to do something with `read` and how the `&` being interacting